# Error Code: 1048

Tags: java, mysql

RandomID cannot be null:

I have a function RandomGen generating random numbers..
ItkTInventory is the DB java file created when i created CRUD using Master Sample Detail Form..
On Save button action performed i want to insert Random number generated to the DB in mysql..

```
private void saveButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    RandomGen rand = new RandomGen();
    ItkTInventory inventory = new ItkTInventory();
    inventory.setSRandomID(rand.randomCode());
    try {
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    } catch (RollbackException rex) {
        rex.printStackTrace();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        List<barcode.ItkTInventory> merged = new ArrayList<barcode.ItkTInventory>(list.size());
        for (barcode.ItkTInventory i : list) {
            merged.add(entityManager.merge(i));
        }
        list.clear();
        list.addAll(merged);
    }
}
```

Comment: Error is self explanatory 'RandomID cannot be null'.

Comment: i did that.. but my main problem was that the random number is not being inserted in the DB..
inventory.setSRandomID(rand.randomCode());
this should have called the set function and inser the data right!!
i am Confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are trying to put null value which is declared as not null in database.

`SOLUTION:`remove not null in database or save with out null value

Comment: Can you elaborate on why that is the solution?

Comment: i did that.. but my main problem was that the random number is not being inserted in the DB..

inventory.setSRandomID(rand.randomCode()); 

this should have called the set function and inser the data right!! i am Confused

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because you are trying to insert null value to a non-null field. Debug you program and make sure RandomID value is not null